# Java Swing GridBagLayout Component Positioning

Tags: java, swing, position, gridbaglayout

I am using `Swing`'s `GridBagLayout` for the fist time and I have so far only added two components to a container, although I intend to add more below vertically. So far, the first component (a `JLabel`) is positioned correctly at `PAGE_START`, and I have remembered to set weight attributes for the components' corresponding `GridBagConstraints`. The second component (a `JTextField`) however is not positioning as I intended and it being centered in the container rather than moving up underneath the `JLabel`. I have attempted to use multiple anchor constants including `FIRST_LINE_START`, `PAGE_START`, `NORTH` & `NORTHWEST` but so far nothing is working.

And so, once again I call for the gifted coders of stackoverflow for help. Below is a snippet of the code and below that is an image of the problem graphically.

```
    // Instantiate components and configure their corresponding GridBagConstraints attributes
    // refPlusType properties
    refPlusType = new JLabel("<html><h3>"+"Reference"+" - "+"Job Type"+" </h3><hr /></html>");
    refPlusTypeGC = new GridBagConstraints();
    refPlusTypeGC.gridx = 0; // Grid position 
    refPlusTypeGC.gridy = 0;
    refPlusTypeGC.gridwidth = 2; // Number of colums occupied by component
    refPlusTypeGC.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10); // Specifies margin
    refPlusTypeGC.weightx = 0.1; // Required for anchor to work. 
    refPlusTypeGC.weighty = 0.1; // Required for anchor to work. 
    refPlusTypeGC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START; // Position in container

    // addressLine1 properties
    addressLine1 = new JTextField();
    addressLine1GC = new GridBagConstraints();
    addressLine1GC.gridx = 0; 
    addressLine1GC.gridy = 1;
    addressLine1GC.gridwidth = 2; 
    addressLine1GC.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10); 
    addressLine1GC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // Specifies component fill Horizontal space
    addressLine1GC.weightx = 0.1; 
    addressLine1GC.weighty = 0.1; 
    addressLine1GC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

    // Add components to this HALLogisticsDetailsPanel
    this.add(refPlusType, refPlusTypeGC);
    this.add(addressLine1, addressLine1GC);
```

Image below;

[image]

Thank you all for any help you can offer.

Comment: What happens if you remove `weighty` values ? Keep only `weightx` values...

Comment: `addressLine1GC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;`

Comment: If I take away weighty, I end up with both elements clustered together in the center of their container, rather than at the top. anchor NORTH was already tried as specified in the question with no change in results.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, wanted to tell you to add `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START`, instead of `LINE_START` and remove all other `anchor` and `weighty` values :-)

Comment: The anchor attribute has no affect unless a weight value is declared, so they clump together in the center of the container if I do that. Although they components are at least in the right position relative to each other

Comment: Instead of learning the nasty GridBag, you might be better of with any of the Big Three third party managers (MigLayout, FormLayout, DesignGridBagLayout - the first being my personal current favourite) - all are both easier to use and more powerful.

Comment: I hear good things about FormLayout, and I know third party layout managers are supposed to be a lot better in many instances, but I've yet to master the Java standard layouts. And I would feel much more comfortable moving onto third party solutions once I have got the basics.

I can't help but feel that if I move to them now I might never get the hang of the rest of the standard layouts.

Comment: good point: I never touched GridBag to any depth - didn't need to waste my time with it, given the alternatives :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I don't like accepting my own answers but here we go. At the end of the day I am trying to get the whole lot to bunch together properly at the top of the container. Adding `weighty` attributes to all the components individually means that the remaining space in the container is distributed between all of them (relative to their `weighty` attribute) therefore spacing them out.

The answer seems to be that by adding a `weighty` attribute to the lowest component in the GridBagLayout, the rest of the remaining space is allocated to below the lowest component and therefore pushing all components to the top. By default is seems that when remaining space is allocated to a component based on it's weight, it is allocated **below** it (at least on the y axis).

Here is the new code with three components to help demonstrate;

```
    // Instantiate components and configure their corresponding GridBagConstraints attributes
    // refPlusType properties
    refPlusType = new JLabel("<html><h3>"+"Reference"+" - "+"Job Type"+" </h3><hr /></html>");
    refPlusTypeGC = new GridBagConstraints();
    refPlusTypeGC.gridx = 0; // Grid position 
    refPlusTypeGC.gridy = 0;
    refPlusTypeGC.gridwidth = 2; // Number of colums occupied by component
    refPlusTypeGC.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10); // Specifies margin

    // addressLine1 properties
    addressLine1 = new JTextField();
    addressLine1GC = new GridBagConstraints();
    addressLine1GC.gridx = 0; 
    addressLine1GC.gridy = 1;
    addressLine1GC.gridwidth = 2; 
    addressLine1GC.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10); 
    addressLine1GC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // Specifies component fill Horizontal space

    // addressLine2 properties
    addressLine2 = new JTextField();
    addressLine2GC = new GridBagConstraints();
    addressLine2GC.gridx = 0; 
    addressLine2GC.gridy = 2;
    addressLine2GC.gridwidth = 2; 
    addressLine2GC.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10); 
    addressLine2GC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // Specifies component fill Horizontal space 
    addressLine2GC.weighty = 1; // Required for anchor to work.
    addressLine2GC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH; // Position in container

    // Add components to this HALLogisticsDetailsPanel
    this.add(refPlusType, refPlusTypeGC);
    this.add(addressLine1, addressLine1GC);
    this.add(addressLine2, addressLine2GC);
```

Comment: `weightx/weighty` indicate how you want extra horizontal/vertical space to be distributed. GridBagLayout will first attempt to allocate the preferred size of each component to each of them. If any horizontal/vertical space is left, then it will sum all the corresponding weights and allocate the extra space with the proportional weight.

Comment: If you take a basic example where you have 3 components (c1, c2, c3) aligned next to each other vertically. The container has a height of 100px and the three component require 10, 20 and 30px (total makes 60px and there are extra 40px vertically). Imagine that c1 and c2 have declared a weighty of 1 and that c3 has declared a weighty of 3 (total of weighty is 5). c1 and c2 will have 1/5 of the extra space-->8px while c3 will get 3/5 of the 40px-->24px. In the end, c1 will have a "cell" of 18px high, c2 will have a cell of 28px high, while c3 will get 54px high (total is then equal to 100px).

Comment: Thank you Guillaume, that now makes much more sense. I will edit my question to give a brief overview of what the finished product is intended to look like, and if you edit your answer to reflect what you've told me in these comments and amend the code then I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try increasing the `weighty` for `addressLine1` to a much larger value. I did a quick test setting it to 1000:

```
addressLine1GC.weighty = 1000.0;
```

and that pushed the `addressLine1` field up under the label with the whitespace below.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I set it to 100 and that did the job. I can't help but feel that the "weight" attributes are little intuitive. If this means I have to manually set a much higher value each time it's going to be a royal pain, but I guess what's done it done.

Comment: Looks like it's not going to work in the grand scheme of things because I have to raise weighty by *1000 each time, which means I will run out of number in a double before I have half the components on.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a problem. It looks like Guillaume has a better answer that makes use of `anchor = NORTH` as well as slightly modified weightx and weighty values.

Answer (score 2):

`anchor = NORTH` works like a charm:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestJPanels {

    private JLabel refPlusType;
    private JTextField addressLine1;

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestJPanels.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        // Instantiate components and configure their corresponding GridBagConstraints attributes
        // refPlusType properties
        refPlusType = new JLabel("<html><h3>" + "Reference" + " - " + "Job Type" + " </h3><hr /></html>");
        GridBagConstraints refPlusTypeGC = new GridBagConstraints();
        refPlusTypeGC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; // Number of colums occupied by component
        refPlusTypeGC.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10); // Specifies margin
        refPlusTypeGC.weightx = 1; // Required for anchor to work.
        refPlusTypeGC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START; // Position in container

        // addressLine1 properties
        addressLine1 = new JTextField(20);
        GridBagConstraints addressLine1GC = new GridBagConstraints();
        addressLine1GC.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10);
        addressLine1GC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // Specifies component fill Horizontal space
        addressLine1GC.weightx = 1;
        addressLine1GC.weighty = 1;
        addressLine1GC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        // Add components to this HALLogisticsDetailsPanel
        panel.add(refPlusType, refPlusTypeGC);
        panel.add(addressLine1, addressLine1GC);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestJPanels().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: By removing weighty from the JLabel, the anchor is now obsolete(ie, not doing anything). I see that this works, but when I add a third component using the same format as addressLine1 is breaks again so that the third component floats in the middle whilst the other two are right at the top.

Comment: @RudiKershaw `PAGE_START` is equivalent to `NORTH` (in horizontal orientation), so it will be centered at the top. Since there is no extra vertical space, it will "only" center horizontally the component within its "cell". If you want all your components to be pushed to the top: either you use `weighty > 0` for the last component (and anchor it `NORTH`), either you add an extra component (transparent) with a `weighty > 0`. For a complete answer, please provide a complete question with the components you want and sketch of the layout you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The best 'tutorial' for GridBagLayout that I have seen was created by Scott Stanchfield.  You can find a link to the PowerPoint presentation he gave at JavaOne 2001 [here](http://javadude.com/articles/javaone/Effective%20Layout%20Management.zip)

There used to be an article online with the same information, but it appears to have been swallowed up by Oracle.

Please read all the warnings about why GBL is not ideal.  If you are determined to use it, Scott gives a great visual lesson on how to determine all the constraints by creating a simple sketch of your GUI.

Jim S.

Comment: Oddly, the first time I looked I had GBL recommended to me as being the best option. Even the oracle website agreed. Now I am starting to see people complain about it and am personally starting to regret choosing it. Feels like i've wasted the day working with it.

Comment: @RudiKershaw GBL is probably the most flexible LM provided with the JRE, but it takes a few more minutes to learn than the other LM. Yet, combining and nesting simpler `LayoutManager`'s can also be quite powerful. If you can use third-party libraries, you can always have a look at MigLayout which is quite popular, very powerful and not too complicated to learn.

Comment: +1, for the link :-) though I have to wait for a while before I can upvote this, since my limit is gone for the day. Again, I am a big fan of `GridBagLayout` no matter what others have to say against it, it's tough to understand at the first glance, but what one can do with it, is simply amazing :-)